# PHP replace string with alternating srings

Tags: php, php4

I have a text something like this:

```
    $sText =    
    "www.domain.com
     www.domain.com
     www.domain.com
     www.domain.com
     www.domain.com
     ...";
```

Now I want to spread the domains to subdomains (e.g. 3 sub-domains), so the result should look like this:

```
$aSubs = array("www.sub1.domain.com", "www.sub2.domain.com", "www.sub3.domain.com"); 
$sResult =
"www.sub1.domain.com
www.sub2.domain.com
www.sub3.domain.com
www.sub1.domain.com
www.sub2.domain.com
..."
```

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your replace callback, do something similar to this:

```
static $i = 0;
'www.' . ($i++ % 3 + 1) . '.domain.com';
```

I'm leaving writing the regex to you (as you didn't give any details.)

PS: The `static` keyword in a function refers to a variable that is maintained between several function calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP 5.3:

```
preg_replace_callback($sText, "#www\.domain\.com#", function() {
    static $index = 0;
    $subdomains = array(
        "www.sub1.domain.com",
        "www.sub2.domain.com",
        "www.sub3.domain.com",
        "www.sub1.domain.com",
        "www.sub2.domain.com",
    );
    return $subdomains[$index++ % count($subdomains)];
});
```

Comment: @Ilysis: Even 5.3 ^^ But you can do the same thing by putting the `function()` code in a separate function and passing the name of the function in quotes to `preg_replace_callack`.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$subdomains = array("www.sub1.domain.com", "www.sub2.domain.com", "www.sub3.domain.com");

$text = <<<XXX
www.domain.com
www.domain.com
www.domain.com
www.domain.com
www.domain.com
XXX;


function createSub($matches)
{
    global $subdomains,$count;
    $index = $count++ % count($subdomains);
    return $subdomains[$index];
}
echo preg_replace_callback(
            "#(www)(\..+)#m",
            "createSub",
            $text);
```